# Why doesn't Ubuntu One Save Purchased Music in the designated Music Folder?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I like all of my music to be in one place - my music partition. However, when I purchase music from Ubuntu One I have to physically move my music from the `~/.ubuntuone` folder and into my music partition.

Is it because of the feature of syncing purchased music to all devices that there is a separate folder? It's a great feature, no doubt, but I still find myself navigating to that folder to move things myself.

Comment: You can tell Banshee to automatically copy imported music into ~/Music. Then you don't have to worry about where U1 feels like storing the files, because Banshee will keep them all organized together for you. Rhythmbox may have a similar feature -- it's been a while since I've used it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I asked this very same question of the developer of the Ubuntu One Music Store Rhthmbox Plugin when it was under development. His response was that the music is in a separate folder because if you synced your entire ~/Music collection you'd (probably) quickly run out of space in your 2GB free space. So only your purchased music is (by default) sync'ed.

Back then you couldn't actually sync random folders as easily as you can now, so it made sense to keep your purchased music separate from your massive Music folder.

He also countered my "I want to see the files" point with "why?". Rhythmbox is quite capable of showing you your music files, can play them, and even load them onto your music player. What's the advantage to being able to see the files in a file manager?

I personally see his points. By way of a comparison, on my wifes OSX Mac there is Music in iTunes and I have no idea where it is on the filesystem, and frankly I don't care :) It gets backed up, and in iTunes I can drag it to a player device if I want to.

Guess the same is true of Rhythmbox. I have learned not to care :)

Comment: But it's better to keep your music bunched together, is it not? Of course I don't want my music folder to be synced, that'd be insane. It seems like this is all because of limitations of U1.

Comment: Your music _is_ bunched together... in Rhythmbox, your music player (or banshee these days). I completely understand the point, but for the average user, so long as they can play their music, and put it on a media player, I'm pretty sure they don't care too much 'where' it is. :)

Comment: I sync all my music, so that it's all available for streaming to my phone wherever I am all the time. As for the other points, I agree with popey (although I suspect that I am the developer he quotes): I look at my music in Rhythmbox (or Banshee). I've got it in four or five folders scattered around my machine, and I never have to worry about it; like popey, I just don't have to care :-)

Answer (score 6):

There's another point not covered by @popey's answer: while there will be a number of people upset by the music not appearing in with the rest of the music, there also will be a number of people upset because the new music is appearing mixed in with their music collection before they have a chance to curate it appropriately. The first group can simply move the files over, whereas the second group would have to hunt down the new music first.

Meanwhile, the rest of us are just listening to the music and not caring where it's coming from.

Comment: I am in the second group and I find having to hunt down my newly purchased music to properly organize it in my collection is annoying!